# How to avoid small caps exceeding pre-defined document margins?

Tags: margins, hyphenation, small-caps

When I use small caps in my document, they occasionally exceed the margins I have defined with the `geometry` package. The underlined part of the name "Lambrecht", which you can see in the picture below, is not supposed to appear outside the margin. The word should be split instead; is there something that can be done about this?

[image: This image illustrates my problem with the name "Lambrecht".]

Here is my preamble:

```
documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

And here is the source of the text passage that I'm concerned about:

```
 In contrast, the direct object in (10b) is syntactically independent from the main clause. Since 
  ``dislocated constituents are by definition optional sentence elements'' (\textsc{Lambrecht} 2001: 
 1065), leaving out \textit{This movie} in (10b) will not cause structural ill-formedness:
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to solve this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @moewe, darn it, you've already commented before my answer was finished. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Off-topic and a bit of speculation. If you are generating citations like "Lambrecht 2001" manually in your document, you are missing out on one of LaTeX's most exicting features: Automatic bibliography and citation generation. You may want to have a look at BibTeX, `natbib` and `biblatex`. See for example https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-12

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies and helpful explanations - I highly appreciate this! I will try to provide a proper MWE next time.

Comment: @moewe: Interestingly, trying with `(Lambrecht 2001: 1065)` reveals that latex does seem to know how to hyphenate "Lambrecht": between the m and the b. Manually adding this hyphenation point to the small caps version as in `(\textsc{Lam\-brecht} 2001: 
 1065)` however results in an overfull box warning.

Comment: @leandriis Oh, that's right. Good catch. Thank you. `\textsc{\hskip0pt Lambrecht}` also hyphenates and so does `\textsc{ls Lambrecht}`. I maintain that it's not the small caps *per se* that cause the problem here, but I have removed my previous comments that claimed there was no hyphenation point in 'Lambrecht'. (I'm guessing the problem here is the 'first words are not hyphenated' rule that apparently also has affect for a font change.)

Comment: @moewe: According to my tests, `\textbf` instead of `\textsc` also does not result in a hyphenation while `\textit` does. Both `{\scshape Lambrecht}` and `{\bfseries Lambrecht}` do also result in a correctly hyphenated word.

Comment: Breaking last names goes against all typographical rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Microtype

It really helps to load the `microtype`-package. I took the liberty of shortening the example to make it truly minimal:

```latex
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt
]{article}

%%% This you don't need anymore %%%
%%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

In contrast, the direct object in (10b) is syntactically independent from 
the main clause. Since ``dislocated constituents are by definition 
optional sentence elements'' (\textsc{Lambrecht} 2001: 1065), leaving 
out \textit{This movie} in (10b) will not cause structural ill-formedness: 

\end{document}
```

## `\-`

If you still get overfull hboxes, you can try to assign hyphenation marks like so: `\textsc{Lam\-b\-recht}` (depends on how this name has to be hyphenated).

[image: Microtype saves the day]

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent reply! This works seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because LaTeX doesn't hyphenate the *first* word in some situations. (I didn't know this was the case for `\textsc`.)

Here is a shorter example document with a smaller page:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\begin{document}
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is myyyyyy shorter example
(\textsc{Lambrecht} 2001: 1065).

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

with the word sticking out. One thing you can do is to add something invisible before it, like @moewe suggested in a comment. It would work with `(\hspace{0pt}\textsc{Lambrecht} 2001: 1065)`.

That would be ugly to type in every place though. But it would be better to introduce a new command for writing these names anyway and use that instead of `\textsc`. So in this version I define a command `\authname`for writing author names which takes care of that in a single place.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\newcommand\authname[1]{\hspace{0pt}\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is myyyyyy shorter example
(\authname{Lambrecht} 2001: 1065).

\end{document}
```

This gives a nicer result:

[image]

Next suggestion: Use Biblatex to handle your references. Then your LaTeX might look like this instead:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sc.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is myyyyyy shorter example
\parencite[1065]{lambrecht}.

\end{document}
```

This needs a file `sc.bib` which defines what the system should know about the `lambrecht` reference (like its title and the year 2001, etc.) The command `\parencite{lambrecht}` inserts a parenthetical reference to the thing we have called "lambrecht" in that file. (Here it is used with an optional argument stating the page number as well.)

This wouldn't work as you want right out of the box, because using smallcaps is not the default and page references are written differently by default. So actually you would get

[image]

So you'd need to customize Biblatex a bit, something like this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sc.bib}

% Authors in small caps
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
% Page numbers after colon
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{%
  \iffieldpages{postnote}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma\space}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\begin{document}
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is a shorter example.
Here is myyyyyy shorter example
\parencite[1065]{lambrecht}.

\end{document}
```

That yields:

[image]

So now everything is good. So what happened with the hyphenation problem? Well, I guess Biblatex took care of that, so just by using the right tool instead of having to change fonts "manually" it just worked as expected.